# How can I build a simple page in React with a cart and few Items to

Tags: reactjs, addition, cart, items

I would like to create a simple page in React.

What I need is few products ( 6/7), I need a cart that increase and decrease when they click on it.

How can be done?

Comment: Did you try to do it and encountered a problem? you should at least try `creat-react-app`  and give it a try until you reach a specific problem which you then post here. I suggest you start by taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.